# Controlling WebKit through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html, webkit

Is there anyway to change properties of webkit through Javascript?

For Example

```
document.getElementById('playBar').style['webkitAnimationDuration'] = '50s';
document.getElementById('playBar').style.webkitAnimationDuration = '4s';
```

I've tried these codes but none seem work in changing the CSS Code once I run the javascript. Everything else in the code runs except for the webkit stuff in CSS, here's the code in CSS I'm trying to change.

```
#playBar {
width: 1px;
height: 12px;
background: white;
float:left;
-webkit-animation: mymove; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-duration: 40s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation: mymove infinite;
animation-duration: 0s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
from {width: 0%;}
to {width: 100%;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
from {width: 0%;}
to {width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: Adding `webkit` as in `.style.webkitAnimationDuration` is the correct way to refer to a prefixed CSS property.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫
Not working though

Answer (score -1):

It seems to work for me now.
Demo: http://jsbin.com/wugixugesafi/1/

I used the following piece of jQuery: 
$("#playBar").css("animation-duration", "1s");

Comment: So there is no other way to control it?

Comment: I'll have a go at doing it and get back to you.

Comment: @コードバリノ - Oliver Barnwell is wrong. `animationDuration` (prefixed with `-webkit-`) [is available on Chrome (WebKit) since as early as Chrome 3.0/Safari 4.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration#Browser_Compatibility). Never trust things on w3schools!

Comment: My bad! You're right @Derek朕會功夫

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫
So how do i control it?
I can't seem to get it to change the properties in Javascript

Comment: I just spent a few minutes trying but I couldn't change it either.

Comment: I know isn't that weird?
I can't adjust it despite it supposedly being able to adjust what gives?

Comment: This works perfectly fine :) : http://jsbin.com/wugixugesafi/1/

Comment: @OliverBarnwell
Can you send a jsfiddle of it?

Comment: @OliverBarnwell
Where's the script that edits the code?
Like i don't see how you can change the value in that code?

Comment: @OliverBarnwell
Isn't there a Javascript code? not Jquery?